# Datatable.js with php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

I have a php foreach code to output all the items from a database in the form of a table after clicking on a button which send ajax request to the php foreach code.But i want to use datatables.js in the table.I called the required files.But its not working.

Comment: You are gonna have to include some code and clarify the problem, otherwise we can't do naught.

Comment: Really! Sometimes it doesn't work.

Comment: do u know fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For eg:
This code works when a button is clicked(using ajax):

```
<?php
foreach($user in $users){
$output = "<div class='table-responsive'><table id='mytable' class='table table-striped'><tbody><tr><td>{$user}</td></tr></tbody></table></div>";
echo $output;
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mytable').dataTable();
}
</script>
```